# Creating an update from insert in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I already have an insert fully working. However i am unable to get the update working. I am using application express and using oracle sql. Below is what i have come up with. However it only seems to be adding new rows, creating a copy. Not updating the current row of data.

```
  DECLARE

  l_upload_size INTEGER;
  l_upload_blob BLOB;
  l_image_id    NUMBER;
  l_image       ORDSYS.ORDImage;
  l_name        VARCHAR2(100);
  l_address        VARCHAR2(100);  
  l_postcode       VARCHAR2(100);
  l_description   VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

  --
  -- Get the BLOB of the new image from the APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES (synonym for WWV_FLOW_TEMP_FILES)
  -- APEX 5.0 change from APEX_APPLICATION_FILES which has been deprecated
  -- APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES has fewer columns and is missing doc_size
  --

  SELECT
    blob_content
  INTO
    l_upload_blob
  FROM
    apex_application_temp_files
  WHERE
    name = :P3_filename;
  --
  -- Insert row into the table, initialising the image and
  -- returning the newly allocated image_id for later use
  --
  INSERT
  INTO
    bars
    (
      filename,
      image,
      name,
      address,
      postcode,
      description

    )
    VALUES
    (
     :P3_filename,
      ORDSYS.ORDImage(),
     :P3_NAME,
     :P3_ADDRESS,
     :P3_POSTCODE,
     :P3_DESCRIPTION
    )
  RETURNING
    image_id, image
  INTO
    l_image_id, l_image;

  -- find the size of BLOB (get doc_size)
  l_upload_size := dbms_lob.getlength(l_upload_blob);
  -- copy the blob into the ORDImage BLOB container
  DBMS_LOB.COPY( l_image.SOURCE.localData, l_upload_blob, l_upload_size );

  -- set the image properties
  l_image.setProperties(); 
  create_blob_thumbnail(l_image_id);

  UPDATE
    bars
  SET
    image     = l_image -- original ORDImage image
  WHERE
    image_id = l_image_id;

END;
```

Comment: Your code does an INSERT unconditionally followed by an UPDATE to the same record, if you need to do an INSERT only if the record does not already exist, you would need to first check that and INSERT only if not exists else do the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) command. Try something like this:

```
MERGE INTO bars DEST_TABLE
USING (select :P3_filename as filename from dual) SOURCE_TABLE
ON (DEST_TABLE.name = SOURCE_TABLE.filename)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
 UPDATE SET  image = ORDSYS.ORDImage()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (
      filename,
      image,
      name,
      address,
      postcode,
      description)
      VALUES (:P3_filename,
      ORDSYS.ORDImage(),
     :P3_NAME,
     :P3_ADDRESS,
     :P3_POSTCODE,
     :P3_DESCRIPTION);
```

Comment: What is meant by DEST_TABLE?

Comment: I have tried this but i am getting a constraint violates error for my primary key.

Comment: DEST_TABLE - is the table where you are going to make insert or update.

Comment: What fields are used for primary key? It must be incorrect isert statment.

Comment: image_id is the primary key field

Comment: expression ON (DEST_TABLE. name = SOURCE_TABLE. filename) should define whether you are going to insert or update. If it evaluates as true "WHEN MATCHED THEN" - will be executed, otherwise "WHEN NOT MATCHED".

Comment: I am confused. sorry, could you explain

Comment: Sure, MERGE command is working following way it chooses execute an update or insert depending on whether it is going to find much in source table (in query above SOURCE_TABLE). A match is found by the expression ON (DEST_TABLE. name = SOURCE_TABLE. File name). The DEST_TABLE - hare is synonyms in general is a table where you are going to make insert or update. You should read more formal and detailed explanations like this(http://gautampartap.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-does-merge-statement-works-in.html) or this (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).